# Require forked gem in bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems

I had to fork a gem from github and make some code changes to suit my needs.  I then put it in my own [github repo](https://github.com/godzilla74/openvas-omp-ruby) using [this resource](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2011/03/15/creating-and-managing-private-rubygems-with-jeweler-github-and-bundler/).

Now, for my app, I've added the gem to my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'openvas-omp', :git => 'git://github.com/godzilla74/openvas-omp-ruby.git'
```

Ran `bundle install` and now I'm trying to run my app but it's throwing an error saying that it can't load my gem:

```
/Users/godzilla74/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- openvas-omp-ruby (LoadError)
    from /Users/godzilla74/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from omp.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

My app is pretty simple so far.  It's just one file `omp.rb`:

```
...some other requires....
require 'openvas-omp'

ov = OpenVASOMP::OpenVASOMP.new("host" => "10.10.10.200", "port" => "9390", "user" => 'admin', "password" => 'admin')
puts ov
```

Here is my current tree of the `omp` app folder:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── omp.rb
```

Have I gone about implementing the gem incorrectly?  From what I understand, I can't simply run the command `gem install openvas-omp` because that will pick up on the original github repo which I forked.

Comment: Are you running the app with bundler exec, i.e. bundle exec rails s

Comment: `bundle exec omp.rb` -> `bundler: command not found: omp.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run you code with `bundle exec ruby omp.rb`

Or you can define bundler in the top of your code:

```
# activate bundler
require 'bundler/setup'
# require all gems
Bundler.require
```

and run it `ruby omp.rb`

Comment: That solution was suggested in the comments... didn't work:  `bundle exec omp.rb -> bundler: command not found: omp.rb`

Comment: You miss `ruby` command before `omp.rb`. The answer is updated with another solution.